# In Swift optional function in block raises error

Tags: ios, swift

Following is the test code:

[image]

In the first one, the onComplete function is not optional, everything is fine.

However, in the second one, an error occurs.

Could anyone explain to me?

---

Updated

The error message is:

[image]

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the function is optional?

Comment: @Lucas, because there might be no callback (i.e. onComplete=nil), I want nothing happens under such circumstance.

Comment: I don't know why it failed, but you can do pass `onComplete` directly without creating a wrapper block. (at least for first case). and please, put code instead of image so people can copy & paste & modify your code without OCR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, in Swift, single expression closure [implicitly returns the result of expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_158).

Even if your blankBlock is `()->Void`, `onComplete?()` returns `Void?` type (i.e. `Void` or `nil`).

You should do like this to ensure the return type of the `animations` closure will be `Void`

```
func test2(onComplete: blankBlock?) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        onComplete?()
        return // <-- return Void explicitly
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options in this case. If you know the onComplete block will exist, then you can force unwrap which looks like this:

```
func test2(onComplete: blankBlock?) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        completeBlock!()
    })
}
```

If you don't know if the onComplete block will exist, then you can test to that the value exists like this (recommended way):

```
func test2(onComplete: blankBlock?) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        if let validBlock = onComplete {
            validBlock()
        }
    })
}
```

Edit to comment: I see your point. I would argue that this is because of what the call to `onComplete?()` is actually returning. Because it is an optional function, it will either execute, or return nil. However, animateWithDuration(_:animations:) expects that you will return Void for the block, however you could potentially be returning nil in this case which would be incorrect. The reason I believe this is because changing your code to the following resolves your issue:

```
func test2(onComplete: blankBlock?) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        onComplete?()
        return
    })
}
```

Comment: I know these two options. But my question is, I thought "func?(...)" is the correct way to call an optional function which will automatically handle the case it is nil. Why can't I do it here?